# Task.Run using custom thread pool

Tags: c#, async-await

I have to address a temporary situation that requires me to do a non-ideal thing: I have to call an async method from inside a sync one.

Let me just say here that I know all about the problems I'm getting myself into and I understand reasons why this is not advised.

That said, I'm dealing with a large codebase, which is completely sync from top to bottom and there is *no way* I can rewrite everything to use async await in a reasonable amount of time. But I do need to rewrite a number of small parts of this codebase to use the new async API that I'be been slowly developing over the last year or so, because it has a lot of new features that the old codebase would benefit from as well, but can't get them for legacy reasons. And since all that code isn't going away any time soon, I'm facing a problem.

**TL;DR: A large sync codebase cannot be easily rewritten to support async but now requires calls into another large codebase, which is completely async.**

I'm currently doing the simplest thing that works in the sync codebase: wrapping each async call into a `Task.Run` and waiting for the `Result` in a sync way.

The problem with this approach is, that it becomes slow whenever sync codebase does this in a tight loop. I understand the reasons and I sort of know what I can do - I'd have to make sure that all async calls are started on the same thread instead of borrowing a new one each time from the thread pool (which is what `Task.Run` does). This borrowing and returning incurs a lot of switching which can slow things down considerably if done a lot.

What are my options, short of writing my own scheduler that would prefer to reuse a single dedicated thread?

**UPDATE**: To better illustrate what I'm dealing with, I offer an example of one of the simplest transformations I need to do (there are more complex ones as well).

It's basically simple LINQ query that uses a custom LINQ provider under the hood. There's no EF or anything similar underneath.

**[Old code]**

```
var result = (from c in syncCtx.Query("Components")
    where c.Property("Id") == id
    select c).SingleOrDefault();
```

**[New code]**

```
var result = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    Dictionary<string, object> data;

    using (AuthorizationManager.Instance.AuthorizeAsInternal())
    {
        var uow = UnitOfWork.Current;
        var source = await uow.Query("Components")
            .Where("Id = @id", new { id })
            .PrepareAsync();
        var single = await source.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        data = single.ToDictionary();
    }

    return data;
}).Result;
```

As mentioned, this is one of the less complicated examples and it already contains 2 async calls.

**UPDATE 2**: I tried removing the `Task.Run` and invoking `.Result` directly on the result of a wrapper async method, as suggested by @Evk and @Manu. Unfortunately, while testing this in my staging environment, I quickly ran into a deadlock. I'm still trying to understand what exactly transpired, but it's obvious that `Task.Run` cannot simply be removed in my case. There are additional complications to be resolved, first...

Comment: And why again you are using `Task.Run` to run already async api? I mean why not `GetSomethingAsync(...).Result`, how `Task.Run` helps here?

Comment: @Evk: Because each small part that I'm rewriting in the old codebase actually consists of a number of separate async calls, as well as some prep work. I simply don't have an existing single async method that would do everything I need at any specific old site.

Comment: I still don't get it. Maybe you can provide some (pseudo code) example of how you are calling your async api from sync codebase using Task.Run?

Comment: Sure. I'll add it to my question!

Comment: Is [ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) an option? If the single synchronous method needs to consecutively call multiple async methods, in order, it seems like that would be an option. Then you can just slap a wait on the end of the chain.

Comment: @pstrjds: I'm sure that *could* be done. But then I'd have to reorganize every method I touch, which again boils down to a lot more work than I have time for. There are sync methods that would call into separate async methods in tens of places, with normal sync code dispersed between them. I'm also not convinced that it would solve my thread switching problem. Where would the tasks run, while I Wait on them?

Comment: Still not very convincing. Block of code inside (async () => ....) already returns `Task<Dictionary<string, object>>`, why not wait for Result of that task? Seems not much value in wrapping that into another task with `Task.Run`.

Comment: @Evk: Ok, I think I get your point. I could write all of these new snippets as local functions that return a Task<WhateverIsNeeded> and avoid the Task.Run call. What I fail to see (and it's probably just my confusion here, TBH) is how this will avoid involving a thread pool and keep the existing expectations of the sync codebase intact? By latter I mean the fact that sync code expects to not switch threads in the middle.

Comment: It will not, just that you are using `Task.Run` in multiple places in your question (and even say that specifically for Task.Run "This borrowing and returning incurs a lot of switching") making it look like `Task.Run` is the source of a problem (even title of question contains Task.Run). Since you cannot control what happens in those async methods you call (they might as well start their own thread, or might not) - you cannot ensure the whole thing will always only use one thread without switching. At least by removing Task.Run you might be able to reduce that switching.

Comment: So first thing I'd suggest in your case is removing Task.Run and test again to see if that improved your perfomance in tight loops (that's not required to move everything to separate methods for that, you can just replace `Task.Run` in your code with custom method which will execute your block of code and wait for Result of returned task).

Comment: Sound likes [CurrentThreadTaskScheduler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/09/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/).

Comment: @Evk: Please consider my 2nd update.

Comment: That means you run this code in something that has notion of "main thread" (wpf, winforms, asp.net). There blocking on async calls like this may indeed lead to deadlocks (you can read why in many places, for example here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: You are correct. This code runs under ASP.NET. So basically I'm stuck with Task.Run and its overhead until all the code can be transitioned to async?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you are on the right track. Wrapping every async call in a `Task.Run` seems horrible to me, it always starts an additional tasks which you don't need. But I understand that introducing async/await in a large codebase can be problematic.

I see a possible solution: Extract all async calls into separate, async methods. This way, your project will have a pretty nice transition from sync to async, since you can change methods one by one without affecting other parts of the code.

Something like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, object> GetSomeData(string id)
{
    var syncCtx = GetContext();
    var result = (from c in syncCtx.Query("Components")
                  where c.Property("Id") == id
                  select c).SingleOrDefault();
    DoSomethingSyncWithResult(result);
    return result;
}
```

would become something like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, object> GetSomeData(string id)
{
    var result = FetchComponentAsync(id).Result;
    DoSomethingSyncWithResult(result);
    return result;
}

private async Task<Dictionary<string, object>> FetchComponentAsync(int id)
{
    using (AuthorizationManager.Instance.AuthorizeAsInternal())
    {
        var uow = UnitOfWork.Current;
        var source = await uow.Query("Components")
            .Where("Id = @id", new { id })
            .PrepareAsync();
        var single = await source.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        return single.ToDictionary();
    }
}
```

---

Since you are in a Asp.Net environment, mixing sync with async **is a very bad idea**. I'm surprised that your `Task.Run` solution works for you. The more you incorporate the new async codebase into the old sync codebase, the more you will run into problems and there is no easy fix for that, except rewriting everything in an async way.

I strongly suggest you to not mix your async parts into the sync codebase. Instead, work from "bottom to top", **change everything from sync to async where you need to await an async call**. It may seem like a lot of work, but the benefits are much higher than if you search for some "hacks" now and don't fix the underlining problems.

Comment: I'll try that and report back tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I understand that (and have for some time). Unfortunately, the amount of code that needs to be modified to do this properly is *insane* and I'm a lone developer. All cautions aside, I've already decided to keep the Task.Run approach as long as it works, because there literally is no other realistic option. I wish the designers of the async/await feature added some way to completely disable the async-ness of the entire continuation chain that could be applied in the vein of ConfigureAwait. This would really help the transitions from old code to new, such as mine.